# What is the name of the rigid plastic cord in this hem?

Tags: sewing, terminology, plastic

I deconstructed a bag/pack in an attempt to sew one from scratch and the hem had a rigid plastic cord that helped it keep its circular shape:

[image: picture of cord]

The best I could find after some time googling is that it looks like "welting cord", but the examples I've found have the same shape but are made out of vinyl.

Is there another name for this type of cord?

Answer (score 7):

Welt cord and **piping cord** are the correct terms.

They come in different varieties, with the center filling being made of different materials, such as foam or rope or cord.

You can also get them *hollow*, and then you buy a cord of your choice to thread through it, such as the rigid plastic cord that you'd like.

Instead of buying pre-made piping cord, you can also [make your own](http://www.makeit-loveit.com/2012/01/sewing-tips-how-to-make-use-piping.html). Again, you end up filling the "pipe" with a cord of your own choosing.

If you choose a rigid plastic cord, you'll lose some flexibility. Which, in a pack/bag, I imagine is the point, as it will retain its shape better when empty.

Comment: @ChrisMendez Well, you pointed me in the right direction with your question!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, and I am not sure I found the exact answer, but let me throw out what I have found so far.  On the [Bag'n-telle website](https://bagntell.wordpress.com/hardware/), I found information about what they call "Framing Scrim," which they describe as

> Dense twisted paper cord or  pliable rubber filler for frame purse making. Great for standard to wide channel purse frames or purses with thin fabric layers. Using scrim in purse making strengthens the bond between the fabric and the frame.  Insert the scrim into the lining side of the purse using a pointed tool (such as wooden creaser/turner).

Here's the picture that they show next to the definition:

[image]

However, I did another search for "plastic welting cord", and found some really promising supplies--many seem to be aimed towards use in boating. Here's an example from [this website](http://www.sailrite.com/Seabrook-Vinyl-Welting-Piping-White?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6NjNBRDKARIsAFn3NMoX3-lt9d0VSc4IvTwYBnEzHLkbKKYV8Xsh5jNUIHB7EA6ULqZpXu4aAgkVEALw_wcB).

[image]

There were a number of other retailers that came up with that particular search term--some of them are for the cordage only, but others sell the cords already enclosed in fabric of some sort (as shown in the picture above).